# Two different queries "with"

Tags: sql

```
    WITH RESULT1 AS (
    SELECT
     **B.StartDate - C.StartDate) AS Test**
    FROM
      Project B
    WHERE
      B.FundingAmount > 0
    )
;
    WITH RESULT2 AS (
    SELECT
      C.StartDate
    FROM
      Project C
    WHERE
      C.FundingAmount > 0
    )
```

The part I'm struggling with is the starred line. That's what I want to do. Take the `StartDate` from `Result1`, and subtract `StartDate` from `Result2`. How would I do this?

I simplified the rest of the query, but essentially, Result1 and Result2 have 2 different where clasue which produce two different results. I'm wondering if I can keep it as is and somehow reference to each other, or if I have to re-write the whole thing entirely.

Thank you

Comment: What is the relationship between the two sets? Is there a Project ID column which your expecting to use in order to match rows from both result sets?

Comment: What rdbms are you using? How are result1 and result 2 joined/connected/related? Tell us what you tried, which errors occurred? Give sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be very close to what you want, but because you don't have a `JOIN` condition between `Result2` and `Project`, my code will generate a Cartesian product (all possible combinations of rows from the two tables / results).

If you know the "equality" condition between these two sets, please replace my `1=1` condition with that condition.

```
WITH RESULT2 AS (
    SELECT
      C.StartDate
    FROM
      Project C
    WHERE
      C.FundingAmount > 0
    )
SELECT Result2.StartDate - P.StartDate
FROM Result2
    INNER JOIN Project P ON 1 = 1
WHERE
    P.FundingAmount > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

in oracle it is just

```
WITH RESULT1 AS (
SELECT
 **B.StartDate - C.StartDate) AS Test**
FROM
  Project B
WHERE
  B.FundingAmount > 0
),
 RESULT2 AS (
SELECT
  C.StartDate
FROM
  Project C
WHERE
  C.FundingAmount > 0
) 
select * from Result1, Result2 where whatever
```